Yarn workspaces - "unknown workspace" error
I have a repo set up to use yarn workspaces. However, when I try to run a script from workspace a, I get an error: Unknown workspace "a".
I also cannot run the script directly from folder a.
cd a
yarn log
yarn run v1.22.19
error Command "log" not found.

My top-level package.json declares workspaces a and b:

{
  "name": "vue-tsc-repro",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "a",
    "b"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.4.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.2.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^2.0.26"
  }
}

In folder a, I have the following package.json:

{
  "name": "a",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "log": "echo hello"
  }
}

It appears yarn simply isn't recognizing the workspaces I've added. When I try to add dependencies to a/package.json they are not installed.
I am using yarn version 1.22.19.
What am I missing?
